# Como criar uma sub matriz a parti de uma matriz no Python?

Tags: python, matriz

Eu consegui gerar uma matriz via Python e através dessa matriz gerada eu tinha que gerar uma matriz 3x3. Mas não sei como fazer isso, tava pesquisando e sei que o próprio Python tem um recurso pra isso, mas não estou achando.

Exemplo:

### Tenho a Matriz:

[image: Matriz Principal]

### Resultado

E através dessa Matriz gerada ela ia me retornar outras Matrizes 3x3 dessa, como nessa da foto abaixo:

[image: Resultado]

Se alguém puder me ajudar e ficarei extremamente agradecido!

Obrigado!

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Eu dei uma resposta, mas tive que ter muita boa vontade porque você não facilitou: ao invés de postar as informações da sua matriz em texto, você usou uma imagem, o que impede qualquer um de copiar e colar (eu tive que digitar tudo, quase não respondi por isso). No futuro, se quiser ter ajuda, procure facilitar a vida dos colegas, ok? Leia a [help]. Lá tem informações sobre como formatar conteúdo na sua pergunta. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simples: use o pacote [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) e faça [*slicing*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). Exemplo:

```
import numpy as np

matriz = np.array([
            [13, 28, 45, 50, 26, 10],
            [27, 24, 22, 33, 88, 11],
            [90, 25, 85, 23, 76, 55],
            [77, 15, 31, 29, 13, 14],
            [66, 41, 50, 20, 47, 11]
         ])

print(matriz[0:3, 1:4])
print('')
print(matriz[2:, 0:3])
```

Saída:

```
[[28 45 50]
 [24 22 33]
 [25 85 23]]

[[90 25 85]
 [77 15 31]
 [66 41 50]]
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/2Ec1T5).

Comment: Opa, excelente dica, Luiz Fernando. Mas tem um porém, esse problema que estou trabalhando é pra minha universidade, e é meio que obrigado a usar o PyCharm, e o PyCharm não reconhece a importação do numpy. Se não for muito incomodo, você sabe me dizer se tem uma maneira do PyCharm reconhecer o numpy ou tem alguma outra maneira para resolver essa questão da matriz? Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Bom, você não menciona na sua pergunta qualquer coisa sobre PyCharm ou sobre impossibilidade de usar o NumPy. Se tivesse mencionado, eu não teria respondido assim. De todas as formas, esse é um outro problema, e por isso eu sugiro que abra uma nova pergunta a esse respeito. No SOen já tem uma que pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815567/problems-with-numpy-in-pycharm. Além do site citado lá, tem esse outro aqui de onde vc pode baixar o NumPy precompilado (se usar Windows): http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ Boa sorte! P.S.: Ah, meu nome não é Luiz Fernando. :)

Comment: Ah, sobre ter outra maneira de resolver, claro que tem. Você mesmo processa os índices da matriz e extraí o que deseja. A lista nativa do Python [também tem *slicing*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation). Não é facilitado como o dos arrays do NumPy, mas com ele e com um laço `for` vc consegue fazer.

Comment: Entendido, Luiz Vieira. Vou procurar fazer o que recomendou. E desculpe pela confusão dos nomes, estou com a cabeça a mil rs. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Não foi nada. Boa sorte!